# SQL Server 2005 IndexOptimize SP against one table's indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, indexing

I'm trying to figure out how to use this `IndexOptimize` stored procedure that I got from http://ola.hallengren.com/ to run against just a single table's indexes.

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(N'database_name'), 
                                     OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.table_name'), 
                                     NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED');'
```

I get this as the result both before and after running the `IndexOptimize` job:

http://cl.ly/image/472J160R1y2n

Here is what I'm trying to run:

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
     @Databases = 'database_name',
     @Indexes = 'database_name.dbo.table_name',
     @FragmentationLow = NULL,
     @FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE',
     @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE',
     @FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
     @FragmentationLevel2 = 30'
```

The query completes, but it doesn't seem to make a difference to the table's indexes. Am I missing something?

Comment: A typical explanation would be a small table. Could you post a screenshot showing the number of pages, and perhaps add some information about the amount of rows in the table?

It might also help to have a look at some of the comments made to a question that might be very similar to your situation, to get some additional ideas about what could have caused it:

http://beyondrelational.com/quiz/sqlserver/general/2010/questions/sqlserver-quiz-general-2010-sankar-reddy-what-is-the-reason-for-high-index-fragmentation-even-after-rebuilding-the-clustered-index-sometimes.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've chosen to only allow your indexes that have > 30% fragmentation to be rebuilt online. Rebuilding an index online is only an Enterprise feature. Are you using SQL Server Enterprise?

Comment: That's correct. I'm using the Standard Edition on this SQL Server. There was confusion at first since there are other SQL Servers in the environment that are using Enterprise.